# Can't seem to display image from folder on server

Tags: php, filesystems

So I'm trying to display images that users upload on the home page. However, while the other info (description, title, username, date variables) shows up fine, the image will not show up for some reason. So can someone point out the error to me that is preventing the image from showing up? The image is stored in the DB and the folder on the server just fine.

Here is the code on my home/index.php page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<?php

include('header.php');

?>

<title>Splindr</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="contentWrapper">

    <?php 

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No SQLI");
            mysqli_select_db($conn, "sample") or die ("No DB");

    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `username` = 'ralston3'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli) or die ("No query");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))   {
        $username = $row['username'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $image_name = $row['image_name'];
        $image_id = $row['image_id'];
        $date = $row['post_date'];
    }

    $image_id = $image_id;

    echo "<div id='photo'><div id='image'><img src='$image_id'><div id='info_header'>$title &nbsp by &nbsp $username &nbsp on &nbsp $date   </div><div id='imageInfo'>$description</div></div></div>";

    ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for my posts_check.php page, where the posts are sent when the user uploads them:

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No SQLI");
                mysqli_select_db($conn, "sample") or die ("No DB");


if (isset($_FILES['image']) && ($_FILES['image']['size'] < 2097152) && (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif')))) {

$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);

mkdir("photos/$rand_dir_name");

if (file_exists("photos/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["image"]["name"]." Already exists";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

//echo "Uploaded and stored in: phoyoss/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES["image"]["name"];

$username = 'ralston3';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_id_before_md5 = "$rand_dir_name/$image_name";
$image_id = md5($image_id_before_md5);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sqli = "INSERT INTO `photos` (username, title, description, image_name, image_id,   post_date) VALUES ('ralston3','$title','$description','$image_name','$image_id','$date')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sqli) or die ("No query");

header('location:index.php');


//$profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
//$img_id_before_md5 = "$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name";
//$img_id = md5($img_id_before_md5);
//$profile_pic_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos VALUES ('','test','$user','$date','$description','http://localhost/tutorials/findFriends/userdata/user_photos/$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name','no','$img_id')");
//header("Location: upload_photo.php");

         }  

    } else { 

        header('location:error.php'); 

    }

?>
```

Comment: What does "view source" reveal when using `echo "<div id='photo'><div id='image'><img src='$image_id'>...`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It shows that the img src = /photos/da188bb648bd896044bac8b4805f7d60 .....da188bb648bd896044bac8b4805f7d60 being the image_id stored in mysqli. However, the image is stored in photos/(random_directory_name)/$image_id ....so you would think  that I should put the (random_directory_name) in the path, but I did that in the posts_check.php. So I'm confused as to why the image still doesn't display

Comment: If you didn't save the "random (folder) path" into DB, it's going to make displaying images very difficult, because you'll need to re-retrieve that random name from the variable it was originally saved under/as. Try and place one of those known images with the path in your address bar to see, then match it up in your echo.

Comment: You may have to add an extra `/` in order for it to tell it "go to root"... if you're trying to access your script that's not inside your root to start with. Something like `<img src='/' . "'.$image_id.'">` but I could be off with that syntax.

Comment: Ah okay. So when I create the `random_directory` column in mysqli and set it to the $random_direc variable in posts_check.php, in index.php would I create a variable and set $someVariable = ".photos/".$random_direc/.$image_id ?

Comment: Something to that effect yes, but the dot in `.photos` should be a `/` you may have made a typo. Viewing source will help a lot too and will guide you as to what should be, and what it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Fred-ii- viewing the src definitely helped me figure the problem out and i'm one symbol away from fixing it now. Thanks. The problem is that when I set >> $actual_image = "http://localhost/splindr_2.0/photos/".$random_directory.$image_id; << everything works fine but there is no separation between $random_directory and $image_id which causes the error. When I go put the "/" in manually everything works great. I thought "." was the proper way to separate variables. What do you suggest?

Comment: A major problem that I also noticed is that you're MD5'ing the folder's creation, then MD5'ing `$image_id` using `$image_id = md5($image_id_before_md5);` and that will cause you some major headaches. I suggest you go over your strategy. First it creates an MD5 folder with 16 chars, and stored as a 33 chars. entry in DB. In turn, losing the reference to.

Comment: To use `/` seperators, you can use `<img src='/photos/$image_id/$image_name'>` which is what I've done so far before debugging the rest of the code. The rest of the issue lies in the MD5 function(s) / variable(s).

Comment: Create a column called `folder` then do this `(username, title, description, folder, image_name, image_id, post_date) VALUES ('ralston3','$title','$description','$rand_dir_name','$image_name','$image_id','$date')` for your UPLOAD code, then your image source would be something like `<img src='/photos/$folder/$image_name'>` and adding `$folder = $row['folder'];` which worked for me. Since the `$rand_dir_name` in `$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);` for upload will be the folder's name saved in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you're inserting the $image_id into the database as an md5 hash, so your

```
<img src='$image_id'>
```

is not pointing to the actual image.